# Wicket 1.5 Javascript File in Body Tag

Tags: javascript, wicket

I need to put a script-tag inside the body, because the javascript doesn't work in the head tag.

As of Wicket 1.5 the following code is not longer supported:

```
add(new JavaScriptReference("wz_tooltip", new JavaScriptResourceReference(BaseTemplate.class, "wz_tooltip.js")));
```

This is because the class `JavaScriptReference` no longer exists.

I can't obviously use the new `renderHead` method.

My workaround so far:

```
WebMarkupContainer script = new WebMarkupContainer("script");
script.add(new AttributeAppender("type", Model.of("text/javascript")));
script.add(new AttributeAppender("src", Model.of("wz_tooltip.js")));
add(script);
```

Really ugly apart from that it doesn't work; can't find the javascript files.

Is there any other workaround or a "right" way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using a urlFor with a resource reference?  Something like..

```
script.add(new AttributeAppender("src", urlFor(new JavaScriptResourceReference(BaseTemplate.class, "wz_tooltip.js"), null).toString()));
```

I wouldn't expect your current method to work out of the box because of Wicket's complex resource management.  Also, while there may be other "right" ways to do things, I've often found that 3rd-Party javascript can be finicky about placement and I still need to fall back on this method for some scripts.

For example, one script I use must be the last element on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It finds the resource now. Here's the compilable code (ResourceReference is abstract and urlFor gives you a CharSequence): `script.add(new AttributeAppender("src", urlFor(new JavaScriptResourceReference(BaseTemplate.class, "wz_tooltip.js"), null).toString()));`

Comment: Updated with compilable code - I haven't migrated to 1.5 yet so I didn't realize that `ResourceReference` had changed so much.

Comment: who is script ? WebMarkupContainer?

Comment: is there a way to do it in wicket 1.4 ?

Comment: @yoav.str Yes, I haven't moved to 1.5 yet.  I believe the class names are different per the above discussion.  I believe you want to use ResourceReference directly.  Basically, long story short, this just takes a basic `<script wicket:id="script" />` and sets the `src`.  You could do it many different ways.