# Writing script src dynamically via wicket

Tags: wicket

I want my page to load javascript dynamically to my ***body***:

```
<script type= "text/javascript" src="this path should be decided from wicket dynamically"/>
```

I am using wicket **version 1.4** therefore **JavaScriptResourceReference does not exist in my version** (for my inspection it wasn't ' )

how can I solve this ? 
thanks in advance :).

Comment: Have a look at my question... and the answers:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993626/wicket-1-5-javascript-file-in-body-tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993626/wicket-1-5-javascript-file-in-body-tag)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I specify my comment into an answer.

You can use this code snippet:

```
WebMarkupContainer scriptContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("scriptContainer ");
scriptContainer .add(new AttributeAppender("type", Model.of("text/javascript")));
scriptContainer .add(
    new AttributeAppender("src", urlFor(
        new JavaScriptResourceReference(
            YourClass.class, "JavaScriptFile.js"), null).toString()));
add(scriptContainer );
```

and the corresponding html:

```
<script wicket:id="scriptContainer "></script>
```

Just change the string `JavaScriptFile.js` to load any other Javascript file.

Comment: who is YourClass.class ? the panel who contain the scriptContainer ?

Comment: Yes, for example. It's just the scope and together with the name it is used to identify your resource.

Answer (score 3):

[`JavascriptPackageResource.getHeaderContributor()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/JavascriptPackageResource.html#getHeaderContribution%28java.lang.String%29) does exactly what you need.

You need nothing in your markup, just add the `HeaderContributor` it returns to your page.

**Update:** For Wicket 1.5 see the [migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html), but it goes like this:

```
public class MyPage extends WebPage {
   public MyPage() {
   }
   public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
     response.renderJavaScriptReference(new PackageResourceReference(YuiLib.class,
       "yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"));
     response.renderCSSReference(new PackageResourceReference(AbstractCalendar.class,
      "assets/skins/sam/calendar.css"));
   }
}
```

If you want to put your `<script>` element in the body, you can simply declare it as a `WebMarkupContainer` and add an `AttributeModifier` to set the `src` attribute. Although in that case wicket won't generate the relative URLs for you, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works before Wicket 1.5 and only adds Javascript files to the head.

Comment: @rotsch We'd really need a versioned Wicket tag.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understood completely.
If you are trying to create and append a script to the body after the page is loaded you should do it this way:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function load_js() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "scripts/YOUR_SCRIPT_SRC.js"; // <---- HERE <-----
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}

    // Wait for the page to be loaded

if(window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load",load_js,false);
else if(window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload",load_js);
else
    window.onload = load_js;

</script>
```

What I did here is create a new `script` element, and then apply to it its source.
That way you can control dynamicaly the `src`. After that I append it to the body.

The last part is there so the new element is applied only after the page is loaded.

Comment: the big thing is getting the src from the serverside (via wicket) dynamically.
your anwser does not help me ...