# Calling a Javascript function from Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I want to pass the output of a block of javascript code in html to its corresponding wicket component. I tried AbstractDefaultAjaxBehaviour and it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I'm working with:

### HTML

```
// In <body>
<div wicket:id="container">
<script type="text/javascript" wicket:id="channelScript">

  function initChannel() {
    window.alert('got it');
  }

</script>
</div>

private WebMarkupContainer container = new WebMarkupContainer("container");
private Label channelScript = new Label("channelScript", "initChannel();");

add(container);
final AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior channel = new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior() {
    protected void respond(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    channelScript.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
        target.add(channelScript); // initChannel is not triggerred
    }
};
container.add(channel);
```

I also tried this:

```
add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onload") {
  @Override
  protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    channelScript.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
    target.add(new Label(channelScript));
  }
}
```

Please what am I doing wrong? Thanks

### UPDATE

I will be passing series of variables from wicket to JS such that every javascript output is displayed using wicket component. I just realized that I will have to make do with dom ready state to begin the interaction. So that's fine. But then I'm still confused and clueless about how the wicket component will change state to receive updated response from javascript. Is there a wicket component that triggers itself asynchronously?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a Label as script container. Wicket has some proper ways to do that.
The following code would be on option (assuming that you are on wicket 1.5)

```
    @Override
public void renderHead(final Component component, final IHeaderResponse response)
{
    super.renderHead(component, response);

    response.renderJavaScript("initChannel();", "myScriptID");
}
```

If you want to perform a script after you site was fully loaded, you can use this:

```
response.renderOnLoadJavaScript("doSomething();");
```

In wicket 1.4 this works differently. You have to use HeaderContributors there.

Comment: I have tested this. It works. Apparently, I want the javascript code in place (within the html body) and not in head. Such that when I need to pass variables between JS and Java through wicketAjaxGet, I can get it right there (i.e where the wicket component is added).

Comment: Can't you define the JS in the head and call it at that place where you want the code?

Comment: How do I do that? Having the javascript to execute on load is not a problem. Having a component to execute asynchronously on load and retrieving value from javascript is what I'm having problems with. I guess this is what AjaxEventBehavior is meant for. But it's not working for me.

Comment: maybe this can help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993626/wicket-1-5-javascript-file-in-body-tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993626/wicket-1-5-javascript-file-in-body-tag)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong because you set a `wicket:id` on your `<script>` part, thus, Wicket will replace it with your `Label`'s content (the javascript function call). Your javascript function is never available because it is never sent to the client. The "good" way of doing what you want is to remove the `wicket:id` from your script tag and in your behavior use the special method `target.appendJavascript("initChannel();");` (or `prependJavascript`) instead of playing with escaping on a `Label`.

Please note that your first method may never work if you never "fire" the ajax behavior, the second one should work when the navigator has finished loading the DOM and trigger the "onload" event on your page (but I am not sure the behavior is correctly binded, never tried this...)

An additional note is that the Javascript you wrote is polluting the global namespace of the window, if you consider using this in a real project, please consider reading documentation regarding namespacing of javascript.

Comment: Thanks. To what component should I add `target.appendJavascript("initChannel()")` to? Also, how do I fire the ajax behaviour? How does AjaxRequestTarget locate the js function? Sorry, I'm a little bit under an illusion due to hours of trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: To understand how things are supposed to work I suggest you put a `AjaxLink` in your page and in the `onClick` method add the JavaScript call you want to test.

Comment: OK. That seems to work. What about if I don't need onClick event. In fact I don't need an event. I just want the js appended to the html markup. Can you just tell me why something like this doesn't work: `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehaviour behave = new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehaviour() { protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) { target.appendJavascript("alert('hey');")}}; add(behave);` I guess because it is not attached to any html markup?

Comment: Basically you need something to trigger the behavior you attached to the component. If you only want to launch the javascript on page load, you don't even need to attach a behavior and you can simply do it using plain javascript (attach a dom ready function).

Comment: For a page load, a could simply use a closure function - which worked when I tried it. As I mentioned in one of my comments, I need the JS code in the body of html - within html tags. I need the JS variables to be available at the exact place where the wicket component was added.

Comment: I am not sure I understood everything you want to do, but I think you can pass variables to your javascript method calls. Please refine your question if you want me to answer it more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a Wicket 6 extension called [wicket-js](http://rauschig.org/wicket-js) which allows you to do this in a very convenient and clean way.

Code for your use case could look something like this

```
add(new JsBehavior() {
    @Override
    protected IJavaScript domReadyJs() {
        return new JsCall("initChannel");
    }
});
```

which translates into what @Till has already provided as a native Wicket solution.

---

If you want the `alert` in there you could do this

```
add(new JsBehavior() {
    @Override
    protected IJavaScript domReadyJs() {
        return new JsStatements(
            new JsCall("alert", "got it"),
            new JsCall("initChannel")
        );
    }
});
```